# React native router flux go back to root scene

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

In my current scene stack, I have 3 scenes A,B and C.
Going back and forth from A to B to C works fine. But I couldn't navigate back to scene A directly from scene C.
Is this possible?
My current code looks like this:

```
<Scene key="root">
  <Scene key="aKey" component={A} />
  <Scene key="bKey" component={B} />
  <Scene key="cKey" component={C} />
</Scene>
```

So far, I've tried adding this code in my C component:

```
Actions.pop
```

But it only navigates back to previous scene(i.e. B component) and I am trying to navigate back directly to root scene (i.e. A component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Actions.pop() ;
That means it will navigate to back screen .
Use

```
Actions.reset('akey')
```

this will navigate to scene A directly.

Comment: I am getting error for this, and the error is "There is no route defined for key KEY, must be one of 'root','app'"

Answer (score 2):

As Rahul mentioned, one way of doing it is

```
Actions.reset('aKey')
```

The other approach that I figured out is

```
Actions.popTo('aKey')
```